# link criteria ms access

Tags: vba, ms-access, subquery

```
stLinkCriteria = "[UpdateStatus] = '" & _
    Forms![Updates-Search Menu]!LookupUpdateStatus & "'" & " And _
    [Office] = '" & [Office] & "'"
```

Just trying to confine my search to a linked criteria. It looks at the update status and office and filters my form correctly. The above code is my base code that currently works. I want to add one more criteria so it looks like this
update status AND (office or shared). Here is my attempt but does not work

```
stLinkCriteria = "[UpdateStatus] = '" & _
    Forms![Updates-Search Menu]!LookupUpdateStatus & "'" & " _
    And [Office] = '" & [Office] & "'" Or _
    "[Forms]![Updates]!ShareWithOtherOffice = -1"
```

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should probably be

```
stLinkCriteria = "[UpdateStatus] = '" & _
    Forms![Updates-Search Menu]!LookupUpdateStatus & _
    "' And ([Office] = '" & [Office] & _
    "' Or [Forms]![Updates]!ShareWithOtherOffice <> 0)"
```

Since AND is performed before OR by default, you must enclose the office stuff in parentheses in order to execute the OR before the AND.

Also I the OR should be within the string.

I am using a Function `Build` which makes it simpler

```
Function Build(ByVal s As String, ParamArray args()) As String
    'Build("LastName = '{0}', FirstName = '{1}'","Doe","John").

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        s = Replace(s, "{" & i & "}", Nz(args(i)))
    Next i
    Build = s
End Function
```

```
sql = "[UpdateStatus] = '{0}' And ([Office] = '{1}' Or {2})"
stLinkCriteria = Build(sql,
                       Forms![Updates-Search Menu]!LookupUpdateStatus, _
                       [Office], _
                       [Forms]![Updates]!ShareWithOtherOffice <> 0)
```

Comment: Any thoughts on to why i get a type mistmatch as well? the sharewithotheroffice is a checkbox

Comment: There is a mismatch of `"` and the `Or` should be within the string, not outside.